# JPA-how to Add record to master table and child table?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I am having two tables One is a Master table called TRANSACTION and second is record of the transaction this table is called TRANSACTION_RECORD.

TRANSACTION

```
CREATE TABLE `e3_transaction` (
  `transactionid` bigint(20),
  `transactiontype` varchar(10),
  `transactionstatus` varchar(10),
  PRIMARY KEY  (`transactionid`)
);
```

TRANSACTION_RECORD

```
CREATE TABLE `e3_as2805msg4` (
  `transectionid` bigint(20),
  `messageType` int(4),
  `cardAcceptorName` varchar(40),
  `adNational` varchar(1000),
  `adPrivate` varchar(1000),
  KEY `transectionidFK` (`transectionid`),
  CONSTRAINT `transectionidFK` FOREIGN KEY (`transectionid`) REFERENCES `e3_transaction` (`transactionid`)
);
```

It will have one to one mapping between Transaction and transaction record. It means one transaction can have only one record. I have kept this table separately for some reasons. So my class will look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "e3_transaction")
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "assigned-by-code")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "assigned-by-code", strategy = "assigned")
    @Column(name = "transactionid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long transactionid;

    @Column(name = "transactiontype", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String transactiontype;

    @Column(name = "transactionstatus", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String transactionstatus;

    @oneToOne
    private TransactionRecord record;
}
```

I want to persist both objects at a same time. when I persist a TRANSACTION, TRANSACTION_RECORD should be persist in it's table. Is there any way to do this ? 
You can change the table structure if you want. Only thing i need it TWO tables.

Answer (score 0):

Works with

```
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapsId
    private TransactionRecord record;
```

TransactionRecord must have an @Id of the same type as Transaction with no value generation.

Tried with Hibernate as JPA 2.0-provider.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options to map this, but it looks like you are handling it with two separate entities.  As both entities share the same primary key value, your reference mapping will need to change based on which entity you wish to have controlling the pk value generation - as it stands, the e3_transaction.transactionid field is being set by two separate mappings; the transactionid long and the TransactionRecord record reference.

If you wish to use the @MapsId as is suggested in the other answer, you will need to move your @GeneratedValue code to the TransactionRecord entity, as the JPA provider will use the value in the referenced TransactionRecord to set the transactionid attribute and the database field. This is a simple elegant solution, but you can also remove the Long transactionid attribute from Transaction and just mark the record reference with @Id (instead of @MapsId).  The long transactionId value within TransactionRecord would still be used as Transaction's id for EntityManager getReference and find calls.

A different option that allows keeping the @GeneratedValue on the transactionid within Transaction is to define the @JoinColumn annotation on the record reference and specify that the field is insertable=false, updatable=false.  You then need to modify the TransactionRecord so that it has a back relationship to the Transaction so that it can pull the transectionid value from the Transaction instance to use as its id.  This can be accomplished by simply marking the relationship with @ID though.